# String reference from XML resource

Tags: android, google-analytics

Is it possible to make a reference to a string from a XML resource?

I want to do something like this:

**values/strings.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_analytics_key">UA-99999999-9</string>
</resources>
```

**xml/analytics.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- THIS KIND OF REFERENCE DOESN'T WORK IN XML/ ASSETS -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">@string/google_analytics_key</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
</resources>
```

I'm using Google Analytics SDK v4, and my primary objective is to use different Google Analytics key for *debug* and *release* without duplicating the whole *analytics.xml*.

I'd appreciate any approach that works using *analytics.xml*, as I don't want to set analytics configuration programatically.

Answer (score 2):

In your app build.gradle script, you can add different build config fields like this:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID", "\"UA-XXXXXXXX-X\""
        //...
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID", "\"UA-XXXXXXXX-X\""
        //...
    }
}
```

And then access the values anywhere via `BuildConfig.ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID`

---

If you don't want to do any coding, you need to create in your `src` folder, the following path and files: 
**NOTE: This will not work on analytics sdk v4 as resources in files at `xml` folder can't have references to other resources** In that case, your only option is to use this technique to duplicate your `xml/analytics.xml` file in `src/debug/res/xml/analytics.xml` and `src/release/res/xml/analytics.xml`

```
<!-- src/debug/res/values/strings.xml -->
<resources>
    <string name="google_analytics_key">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>
</resources> 


<!-- src/release/res/values/strings.xml -->
<resources>
    <string name="google_analytics_key">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>
</resources>
```

and remove `google_analytics_key` from your default `strings.xml`. This way, the Build System will pick the resource from the correct file depending on current build variant.

For more information on this subject, refer to [Configuring Gradle Builds](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)

Comment: How can I make analytics.xml references this string resource created by Gradle? Google Analytics SDK is loading the hole configuration from this XML like this: analytics.newTracker(R.xml.analytics)

Comment: With the proposed answer you need to create your tracker this way: `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker(BuildConfig.ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID)`

Comment: Thanks, Gero, but I'm looking for an approach that uses this XML, so I can isolate the analytics configuration from the code.

Comment: @marcioggs the answer was edited to suit your approach

Comment: Thanks again, Gero! But in the second approach I'd still have to reference a string resource from a XML resource, right? And I don't know how to do that...

Comment: @marcioggs in the second approach, you can leave your `xml/analytics.xml` exactly as your question. You don't have to pick `google_analytics_key` anywhere in code, just reference it where you want via `@string/google_analytics_key`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75872/discussion-between-marcioggs-and-gero).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

```
public static String getGoogleAnalyticsKey(Context context){
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG ? context.getString(R.string.analitcs_debug) : context.getString(R.string.analitics_store);
    }
```

This solution is not the most elegent, but I couldn't resist trying if it will actually work. Surprisingly it does :D

At the very top, just below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` put the definition of variable

```
def resourceString = "";
```

In your build types, declare them. This is what you need to change.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resourceString = "UA-99999999-9"
    }
    release{
        resourceString = "UA-11111111-1"
    }
}
```

Below everything else, post these lines

```
def String makePath(String... args){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(args.length);
    for(String s : args){
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(File.separator);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

def fix_strings_file(String filePath, String replacement){
    def fileExists = new File(filePath).exists() //Check if it exists, it may already be deleted
    if (fileExists) {
        def newFileContent = new File(filePath).getText()
        newFileContent = newFileContent.replaceAll("(name=\"google_analytics_key\"\\s*>).*(<)", "\$1" + replacement + "\$2")
        new File(filePath).write(newFileContent)
    } else {
        println "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! File :" + filePath + " not fixed, because it doesn't exist !!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    }
}

task changeResouceFile << {
    String stringsPath = makePath("$rootProject.projectDir", "app", "src", "main", "res", "values") + "strings.xml"
    fix_strings_file(stringsPath, resourceString)
}

preBuild.dependsOn changeResouceFile
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm avoiding setting Google Analytics programatically.

Comment: how about this version? :DDDD

Comment: Wow! We have a Gradle/Groovy pro here. Didn't even imagined I could do  something like that.

Comment: Of course you can. Trust me, I would know, I have done magic with gradle in the past. For a good performance, I suggest you create a new file and name it analytics.xml and keep only the analytics string inside, this way it will read the content fast and also write the content fast.